# how can I send mail using symfony 1.4 using gmail and without configuring factories.yml?

Tags: php, email, symfony-1.4

I am trying to send an email from symfony 1.4 (yes, i know its old) but I want to send it through my gmail account and I just cant find a configuration that allows me without need to configure my credential on factories.yml (due I am saving the account that will send the email on my DB) , there is any other way to do this?

Until this moment only like this I can send

```
$message = $this->getMailer()->compose();
$html = "test";
$message->setSubject("test mail");
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
$message->setTo("me@gmail.com");
$message->setFrom("anotheraccount@gmail.com");
$result = $this->getMailer()->send($message);
```

Comment: Just because it's old, doesn't mean it isn't any good. I <3 1.4. Can you post some code so we can see what you are trying to do? The first thing that comes to mind is to store the credentials via the app.yml file and just reference them when you are building out the mail object.

Comment: Sure, thanks, could you see my edit?

Answer (score 2):

According to swift_mailer [docs](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html), you can set the username and password against the transport object. And according the Symfony [docs](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/mailer/sfMailer.class.php), you can access the transport object. So try this:

```
$this->getMailer()->getRealtimeTransport()->setUsername('username');
$this->getMailer()->getRealtimeTransport()->setPassword('password');

$message = $this->getMailer()->compose();
...
```

Comment: I get a fatal error :s you mention is also available storing the credtians in the app.yml, could you give me an idea of how is that please?

Comment: Can you post the fatal error? Sure I'll post how to do it via the app.yml, but first lets see if we can override the values.

Comment: I am very new on symfony, and still I couldnt set the test mod (I change it on index.php but I get many errors sayings I need more conf files) so, basically I only get "Internal error at the screen... and unfortunately no logs (I really wonder why my error log dont get anything

Comment: Are you using the prod or dev environment? In dev environment you will get extensive info about the error on the screen. If you're using prod you have to enable logging in your factories (http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/22?orm=Doctrine#chapter_22_sub_logging) and settings file (`logging_enabled: true`)

Comment: Not even sure how to help him. @jpganz18: Can you post the code from your index.php file? If Symfony is complaining about missing conf files, it leads me to believe you may not have it set up correctly.